# Is it efficient to use max float for boundingRectWithSize for height

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In Objective-C when calculating the size required for given text, we use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` with the size parameter set to the constraining size. Width is usually where the text should break with height being the more flexible axis. Mostly I have seen CGFLOAT_MAX used for height. I've also seen the height specified to the bounds of a parent view (or some similar reasonable value).

```
[someText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil].size
```

My question is, does it matter? Is one method more efficient than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with "efficient". It has to do with what they mean and what they do.

- `CGFLOAT_MAX` is a way of guaranteeing that the height can be as big as it needs to be. Use it if you don't care how tall the text can be. It is, in effect, an unlimited potential height (though of course the *actual* height will not be unlimited).
- Use a limited height if you *do* care how tall the text can be. In other words, if you have a *reason* to want the layout to fail if it can't fit in a certain height, limit the height. You'll know you've failed if the resulting width or height exceeds the width or height you specified (or, in the case of your code, if you get a zero size).

Comment: Great answer @matt. Thanks. Re "efficiency": using max float (instead of a "reasonable value") seemed lazy to me from a programmer's perspective, and so I imagined inefficient for execution. It's a non-obvious API. Kind of like using "-1" to mean something when it really means nothing at all.

Comment: It's not at all like using "-1" to mean nothing. It means exactly what it says. It really does mean "as large as possible", because this parameter is a CGFloat and `CGFLOAT_MAX` really is the largest value it can adopt.